# Counting the frequency of a repeating character substring in Python? Consider max repetition of the character not the min as seen in count( )

Tags: python, substring, frequency

The desired function calls and outputs of required_function() are expected like followings:

```
>>> print(required_function("1112211000022", "1"))
0
>>> print(required_function("1112211000022", "11"))
1
>>> print(required_function("1112211000022", "111"))
1 
>>> print(required_function("1112211000022", "0"))
0
>>> print(required_function("1112211000022", "00"))
0
>>> print(required_function("1112211000022", "0000"))
1
>>> print(required_function("1112211000022", "22"))
2
```

Let's try python's count() function but it extracts non overlapping counts using minimum matching length of the search substring.

```
"1112211000022".count('11') #returns 2 but desired output is 1 because "11" is present only once.
"1112211000022".count('1') #returns 5 but desired output is 0 because "1" is not present.
"1112211000022".count('0') #returns 4 but desired output is 0 because "0" is not present.
```

**Goal:** This function can be helpful in counting occurrence of an amino acid within a protein sequence. I am also trying to write an efficient code, will share soon as I get it done. The function should be time efficient as there will be around 50,000 protein sequences of an average length 250 in a single file related to a single Specie.

Comment: Why doesn't the last example: `print(required_function("1112211000022", "2"))` follow the same logic as the first and output `0`?

Comment: Might be simpler to do the "extended" version right away, without using what you're asking for here.

Comment: @Mark and Kelly Bundy, I have deleted the confusing lines.

Comment: @mAge you haven't explained the last example: `required_function("1112211000022", "2")` Why is the desired response for this `2` and not `0`?

Comment: @Mark, there is an edit in function call required_function("1112211000022", "2") , I want to write required_function("1112211000022", "22"). Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @KellyBundy , my confusion is resolved by -Mark. Thanks to both of you. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to be doing this kind of analysis, you should become well-versed in [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). They are a frequently-used tool for analyzing sequences like this. You current problem is handled easily by setting up a regex using negative lookahead/lookbehind that looks for the target that doesn't follow and isn't followed by the character in the pattern. One way to do it is:

```
import re

def required_function(s, t):
    c = t[0]
    rx = re.compile(f'(?<!{c}){t}(?!{c})')
    return len(rx.findall(s))

assert(0 == required_function("1112211000022", "1"))
assert(1 == required_function("1112211000022", "11"))
assert(1 == required_function("1112211000022", "111"))
assert(0 == required_function("1112211000022", "0"))
assert(0 == required_function("1112211000022", "00"))
assert(1 == required_function("1112211000022", "0000"))
assert(2 == required_function("1112211000022", "22"))
```

This will churn through 50,000 examples in a few milliseconds and could be improved by wisely re-using the compiled regex whenever possible.

Comment: it's working. Thanks. What is the purpose of assert here?

Comment: The asserts are just a demonstration that your test cases pass.

Comment: as this function will be called many times. Shouldn't we compile the regular expression outside the function body?

Comment: @mAge yes, that would be an improvement and it's what I was getting at with the last sentence of the answer.  How you do that, however, will depend on your actual searches since you need a regex for each thing you are counting.